How can i use tesseract in my azure web app service?
I have a web app(model view controller), that uses tesseract, but I don't know how to upload tesseract to azure web app service. I need tesseract to work on azure web app, because at the moment, if I run the web app, The tesseract feature doesn't work.
If I publish the web app through azure devops, it says I have files outside my solution, which I think is the tesseract causing the problem.
I expected , when I upload the web app, I thought that it would work, because it works on my local device, but, when it comes to the tesseract feature, running it from Azure, I get errors "This page is not available" and so on.

Which application (Framework) you are using for the webapp?

I am using windows .NET 8


I need tesseract to work on azure web app, because at the moment, if I run the web app, The tesseract feature doesn't work.

Download the latest Tesseract installer for Windows

Place tesseract.exe and tessdata folder are in the tesseract directory the tessdata folder (containing eng.traineddata) inside the tesseract directory.

Project structure:
- WebApplication2
  - Controllers
    - OcrController.cs
  - tesseract
    - tesseract.exe
    - tessdata
      - eng.traineddata
  - Program.cs
  - WebApplication2.csproj


Include the Tesseract files in the output directory. Add the below ItemGroup to your .csproj file

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="tesseract\tesseract.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="tesseract\tessdata\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

OcrController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tesseract;

namespace TesseractWebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OcrController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("ocr")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Ocr([FromForm] IFormFile image)
        {
            if (image == null || image.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No image provided");
            }

            // Create a temporary file to store the uploaded image
            var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            await using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(tempFilePath))
            {
                await image.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            // Perform OCR on the image
            var ocrResult = PerformOcr(tempFilePath);

            // Clean up the temporary file
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);

            // Return the OCR result
            return Ok(ocrResult);
        }

        private string PerformOcr(string imagePath)
        {
            try
            {
                // Set the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable to the path of the tessdata directory
                var tessDataPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "tesseract", "tessdata");
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TESSDATA_PREFIX", Path.GetDirectoryName(tessDataPath));

                // Initialize the Tesseract engine with the path to the tessdata directory and language
                using var engine = new TesseractEngine(tessDataPath, "eng", EngineMode.Default);

                // Load the image and perform OCR
                using var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imagePath);
                using var page = engine.Process(img);

                // Return the recognized text
                return page.GetText();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Return an error message if OCR fails
                return $"Error: {e.Message}";
            }
        }
    }
}

Navigate to Configuration > Application settings.

Add a new  TESSDATA_PREFIX give the value as the path where tessdata is located (/home/site/wwwroot/tesseract/tessdata)

Deployment status:

Result:

